# How to hide header line in C++ mode?

Tags: c++, header-line

I really don't want emacs to show me which function the pointer is currently inside. (See the photo)

What is the name of that frame? How can I remove it or make show an empty line?

I am using Emacs 25 on Ubuntu 18.10.

[image: Remove headline]

Comment: Try the menu item "Development -> Stick Top Tag To Headerline" That is the command `global-semantic-stickyfunc-mode`.

Comment: yay it works (: Thank you!

Comment: But how can I make this permanent?

Comment: Customize variable `global-semantic-stickyfunc-mode`

Comment: Is that available without installing all of semantic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are seeing the header line of `semantic-stickyfunc-mode`.

There are essentially two ways to switch it on/off.

You can globally switch it on/off by customizing `global-semantic-stickyfunc-mode`.
The graphical user interface offers the menu item `Options -> Customize Emacs -> Specific Options...` for that purpose.

---

You can also switch it off specifically in the c mode family.

Therefore keep `global-semantic-stickyfunc-mode` switched on and put the following code lines into your init file:

```el
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook (lambda () (semantic-stickyfunc-mode -1)))
```

---

The other way around:

Switching it on specifically for the c mode family works by switching `global-semantic-stickyfunc-mode` off and putting the following line into your init file:

```el
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'semantic-stickyfunc-mode)
```